# Problem with exporting and appending data to csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

The situation is the following - I've got a csv file with number of columns (let's say 3) and custom object with same columns but one will be a new one. I want to compare column names and if there is a new one, then add column and then add values accordingly to csv file and I don't want to replace all existing content in current csv file. Here is the code I've written, but I'm getting error: *The appended object does not have a property that c
orresponds to the following column: column1. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry the command.*

File sample: [image: csv file sample]

Output should be same file, but with new column 'column4' and new row containing, like this: [image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
$file_path = '..path_to_the_file\test_csv.csv'
$csv = import-csv -path $file_path

$columns = @([pscustomobject]@{
    column1 = 'something_new_1'
    column2 = 'something_new_2'
    column3 = 'something_new_3'
    column4 = 'something_new_4'
}
)
$csv_columns = ($csv | get-member).where({$_.Membertype -eq 'NoteProperty'}).Name
$columns = ($columns | get-member).where({$_.Membertype -eq 'NoteProperty'}).Name
$compare = $columns | Where-Object {$csv_columns -notContains $_}
foreach ($column in $csv) {
    $column | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $compare -value ''
}

$csv | export-csv -Path $file_path -NoTypeInformation

$columns | export-csv -path $file_path -Append -NoTypeInformation -force
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the input file and the expected output file?

Comment: I've edited initial post to show input and expected files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to streamline the process, this of course assumes the objects you want to *append* already has the same properties as the ones in the array of objects and will only add new ones.

```bash
function Add-ObjectNormalized {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [object[]] $AddObject
    )

    begin {
        $isFirstObject   = $false
        $propertiesToAdd = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(
            [string[]] $AddObject[0].PSObject.Properties.Name,
            [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
        )
    }
    process {
        if(-not $isFirstObject) {
            $isFirstObject = $true
            $propertiesToAdd.ExceptWith([string[]] $InputObject.PSObject.Properties.Name)
        }

        $psobject = $InputObject.PSObject.Properties
        foreach($prop in $propertiesToAdd) {
            $psobject.Add([psnoteproperty]::new($prop, $null))
        }
        $InputObject
    }

    end {
        $AddObject
    }
}
```

Pipe it after `Import-Csv` including the array of objects to be added as argument. For example:

```
$objects = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        column1 = 'something_new_1'
        column2 = 'something_new_2'
        column3 = 'something_new_3'
        column4 = 'something_new_4'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        column1 = 'something_new_5'
        column2 = 'something_new_6'
        column3 = 'something_new_7'
        column4 = 'something_new_8'
    }
)

Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv | Add-ObjectNormalized $objects |
    Export-Csv path\to\newCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output using a simple Csv like the one in question would be:

```
column1         column2         column3         column4
-------         -------         -------         -------
va1             val2            val3
something_new_1 something_new_2 something_new_3 something_new_4
something_new_5 something_new_6 something_new_7 something_new_8
```

Comment: I'm digging into this function and can understand how it works, but is there any more simple way to achieve the same?